# Can not add '.* " at mapping of IIS

Tags: iis, mapping

I am unable to add .* at extension mapping in IIS (defaultwebsite -> properties -> home directory -> configuration)  because it gives the message "Wrong file Extension".

The operating system is Windows 2003 server.
I can add .* at mapping in IIS when the operating system is Windows XP

Comment: In fact the error message is "Wrong extension format."

Answer (score 5):

IIS6 has a second list for wildcard mappings. It's located just below the regular list of mappings and is called "wildcard application maps".